# Ubuntu/Vagrant makes me log in every time I run a program within virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant

I am using Vagrant and Virtualbox running a virtual instance of Ubuntu.  Every time I use the following command "exec /vagrant/build/test_gui" the logs and output of that program show for a split second (not long enough to even try to read the text) before clearing the terminal and displaying the login once again. (pictured below)  I am fairly new to all of these systems and would like to know how to stop this from happening so I can see the output of my program within the virtual machine's terminal? When I use vagrant ssh or vagrant ssh -- -X, and run the same command, it returns an error regarding not being able to find a display.  I am aware this is probably what is resetting the terminal, and I am working on fixing this, but it is rather secondary- what I need is for my terminal to not reset every time there is an error! Is this possible?

Terminal with the following text:

```
Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS ubuntu-bionic tty1
ubuntu-bionic login:
```

[image]

Also, because I cannot seem to find an answer anywhere on the internet, **is "exec" the way I should be running executable?**

I cannot seem to figure out how to both make and also run executables in this reference environment.

Pls help.

Edit.

Fixed this- Had to reset and redo environment variables, amongst other things.  Unrelated BSODs in the past week seem to have corrupted a bunch of stuff, thought i got it all; guess not. Will close when i figure out how to

Comment: Please don't use comments to ask a new question. This is a question answer site where one question at a time of the policy. The comments are our channel to ask you for clarifications. Additional information about the question should be edited into to question.

Comment: I just had a thought, Did you install the server version of Ubuntu?

Comment: Noted- thanks for the tips, I'm pretty new here. Went ahead and read the post rules (probably shouldve before posting. lol.)  
In terms of my ubuntu version I did not manually install it, the only packages I installed myself were vagrant and virtualbox.  Ubuntu seems to have been installed by virtualbox.  I looked around to see how to check for server vs desktop version, and according to what uname -a returned I seem to have the generic version rather than the server version.  I will see if changing this fixes my issue :D

Comment: The server version does not have any GUI. so a login prompt you see is normal. I am not familiar with Vagrant and virtualBox, So, I can't help you if Ubuntu is installed by Vagrant and VirtualBox.

Comment: "**is "exec" the way I should be running executable?**" I'm not sure about your context, but `exec` is a shell builtin that tells the shell to *replace itself* with the given command. When used from a login shell, it should not be surprising that it returns you to the login prompt